# How to query a mongoDB subdocument after finding the parent document

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to query a subdocument of a *specific* document in my mongoDB database using mongoose. I would like to first run a query to get a specific users document, and then subsequently query an array of subdocuments to find one which matches a specific id.

To give some context here is my data structure

[image]

Each document is for a specific user, and the `articleVotes` subdocument contains articles they have voted for. After using my `User`mongoose model to find the current users document via `User.findOne({_id: req.user._id))`, i want to then check if they have up-voted a specific article yet, by doing something like `findOne({_id: articleId, voteType: "1"})`. However, because it's a subdocument i'm stuggling to work out how to do this. Can someone explain how i can do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/index.html) operator,

#### MongoDB v4.4 to support in `findOne()`

- `$filter` in projection to iterate loop of `atricleVotes` array and filter using condition `articleId` and `voteType`

```
db.collection.findOne({
  _id: req.user._id,
  "atricleVotes.articleId": articleId
},
{
  _id: 1,
  atricleVotes: {
    $filter: {
      input: "$atricleVotes",
      cond: {
        $and: [
          { $eq: ["$$this.articleId", articleId] },
          { $eq: ["$$this.voteType", 1] }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
})
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ew4yH4IW4Sd)

---

#### MongoDB v3.2 or Above

- `$match` you conditions
- `$addFields` to get same $filter operation and get filtered `atricleVotes`

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      _id: req.user._id,
      "atricleVotes.articleId": articleId
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      atricleVotes: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$atricleVotes",
          cond: {
            $and: [
              { $eq: ["$$this.articleId", articleId] },
              { $eq: ["$$this.voteType", 1] }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/lZ_EMtdJDe2)